# bash wont assign variables

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I can't get my bash script to assign variables within a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

usercount=0
for word in userfile
do
    let usercount=$usercount+1
done

echo $usercount
```

Output for usercount is always 0. Whats wrong with this?

Comment: For me this outputs `1` not `0`. The `word` variable gets the value `userfile`, `usercount` is incremented and the loop terminates.

Comment: Did you consider using `grep -c 'word' /path/to/userfile` to count occurrences ?

Comment: Are you sure `Output for usercount is always 0`? With your code it should be coming as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `while loop` to read the file `line by line`:

```
usercount=0
while read l; do
  let usercount=$usercount+1;
done < userfile
```

Though just to count line you can very well do:

```
usercount=$(wc -l < userfile)
```

Comment: I agree that the I/O redirection is probably what's intended, but the code should read one word from the list (the word being `userfile`).

Comment: Oh sorry I overlooked `usercount ` coming as `0`. It should be `1`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count lines or words in a file, use `wc`:

Words:

```
wc -w < file
```

Lines:

```
wc -l < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people normally use double parentheses for shell arithmetic:

```
usercount=0
for word in userfile groupfile elephants
do
    ((usercount++))
done

echo $usercount
```

This snippet echoes `3`, corresponding to the three words. You can also use `let`; most people don't. However, when I run your code, it echoes `1`.